# Dehydrating cake?

Tags: cake, dessert, dehydrating

I've recently purchased a book on desserts. Many recipes involve baking a cake and then dehydrating it over night (at 50° C) using the appropriate equipment. I wonder: What kind of kitchen equipment can be used to dehydrate cake?

I am referring to various recipes from the book "Elements of Desserts" by Francisco J. Migoya. (It was originally in English, but I purchased a translated copy.)

For example, he created red velvet truffles. The outside of the truffles is covered in dry red velvet crumbs, as seen on the cover of the book: [Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3875151275)

These crumbs are created using a "dehydrator". I only know this kind of equipment for drying fruit, not cake. Can I use the same thing for cake?

Comment: I have never heard of this technique   can you provide  more details?   And what do you  mean by kind of kitchen?

Comment: 50C sounds like a dehydrator, maybe? Are you translating from this book or did they actually call it desiccating, without mentioning equipment?

Comment: 50 C is about 125 F.  I am now wondering if these are recipes for meringue or dacqoise layers, which often are dried overnight.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I added some more information to my post :-)

Answer (score 3):

For the specific application of creating dried cake crumbs to use as a coating on the outside of other cakes, or confections like truffles, no specific equipment is required.

A low oven is sufficient, perhaps by heating to a moderate temperature like 250 F / 121 C, then turning it off.  The remnants would be crumbled and spread out on a sheet pan, and placed in the oven until quite dry to the touch.  Overnight would be quite common; the crumbs would dry out in the cooling oven.

The specialized equipment to do this is called a food dehydrator and is no different than the one used for fruit.  It would certainly be effective, but is not necessary.